# SSE2 intrinsics: access memory directly

Tags: optimization, assembly, sse, simd, intrinsics

Many SSE instructions allow the source operand to be a 16-byte aligned memory address. For example, the various (un)pack instructions. PUNCKLBW has the following signature:

> PUNPCKLBW xmm1, xmm2/m128

Now this doesn't seem to be possible at all with intrinsics. It looks like it's mandatory to use _mm_load* intrinsics to read anything in memory. This is the intrinsic for PUNPCKLBW:

> __m128i _mm_unpacklo_epi8 (__m128i a, __m128i b);

(As far as I know, the __m128i type always refers to an XMM register.)

Now, why is this? It's rather sad since I see some optimization potential by addressing memory directly...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The intrinsics correspond relatively directly to actual instructions, but compilers are not obligated to issue the corresponding instructions.  Optimizing a load followed by an operation (even when written in intrinsics) into the memory form of the operation is a common optimization performed by all respectable compilers when it is advantageous to do so.

TLDR: write the load and the operation in intrinsics, and let the compiler optimize it.

**Edit:** trivial example:

```
#include <emmintrin.h>
__m128i foo(__m128i *addr) {
    __m128i a = _mm_load_si128(addr);
    __m128i b = _mm_load_si128(addr + 1);
    return _mm_unpacklo_epi8(a, b);
}
```

Compiling with `gcc -Os -fomit-frame-pointer` gives:

```
_foo:
movdqa      (%rdi), %xmm0
punpcklbw 16(%rdi), %xmm0
retq
```

See? The optimizer will sort it out.

Comment: I wouldn't complain if the compiler optimized it, but at least clang and gcc don't. This is easy to check with the -S option. I find verbatim intrinsics -> assembly translations for almost any intrinsic and can map registers directly to variables. Looks like these compilers hardly optimize SIMD intrinsics code...

Comment: @dietr: clang and gcc both do this optimization, as you can see in my example.  Are you building with optimization turned off?  Try using `-O1` or higher.

Comment: I'm using -O2. I guess gcc/clang simply don't see any optimization potential in my particular piece of code...

Answer (score 3):

You can just use your memory values directly. For example:

```
__m128i *p=static_cast<__m128i *>(_aligned_malloc(8*4,16));

for(int i=0;i<32;++i)
    reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(p)[i]=static_cast<unsigned char>(i);

__m128i xyz=_mm_unpackhi_epi8(p[0],p[1]);
```

The interesting part of the result:

```
; __m128i xyz=_mm_unpackhi_epi8(p[0],p[1]);
0040BC1B 66 0F 6F 00      movdqa      xmm0,xmmword ptr [eax] 
0040BC1F 66 0F 6F 48 10   movdqa      xmm1,xmmword ptr [eax+10h] 
0040BC24 66 0F 68 C1      punpckhbw   xmm0,xmm1 
0040BC28 66 0F 7F 04 24   movdqa      xmmword ptr [esp],xmm0
```

So the compiler is doing a bit of a poor job -- or perhaps this way is faster and/or playing with the options would fix that -- but it generates code that works, and the C++ code is stating what it wants fairly directly.